# What is the adjective meaning "great in area"?

Tags: adjectives, derivational-morphology

We have

- length → long
- volume → voluminous

But what is the corresponding adjective for "area"?

I've found "areal", but it seems that this means "pertaining to an area", rather than "having area" or "great in area".

Comment: You could you *vast*.

Comment: _Two-dimensional_. Two-dimensional things have area; three-dimensional things have volume. _Voluminous_ doesn't really mean 'the property of having volume'; it means 'large; capable of containing much'.

Comment: @JohnLawler Could be three-dimensional too. Multidimensional generally refers to three or more dimensions. Polydimensional refers to many dimensions. Oligo-dimensional might work for two or more, implying the possibility of area, but it doesn't seem to be a well accepted word. Of course, 'having dimension greater than one' is unsatisfying.

Comment: Three is all there's room for in the spatial language. Humans live in a 3-D world, though we can only move in 2 of them freely. This makes dimensionality a really big deal for all languages. It shows up in classifier systems, and in English phonosemantics. Words starting with [`ST`- tend to refer to long thin things](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/st.pdf), words beginning with [`FL`- to flat things](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/fl.pdf), and words ending in [-`UMP` to 3-D things](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ump.pdf).

Comment: 'Voluminous' is not defined as 'pertaining to / having volume' in any of the dictionaries I've checked. For instance, RHK Webster's has the following senses only: **voluminous** adj.
1. filling or sufficient to fill a volume or volumes: a voluminous correspondence.
2. writing copiously or at great length: a voluminous writer.
3. of great volume, size, or extent.
4. having ample folds or fullness: voluminous skirts.
5. having many coils, convolutions, or windings. You want 'voluminar'. And neither does 'long' mean 'pertaining to / having length'. That's 'linear'. 'Areal' works.

Comment: Stewart, "long" **does not mean** "having length" and "voluminous" **does not mean** having volume. Exactly as John says, your question and title are totally at odds.

Answer (score 5):

**Expanse**: the area of something; a large and usually flat open space or area

**Expansive**: covering a large space or area

Length → Long
Volume → Voluminous
Expanse → Expansive

Answer (score 3):

There is a technical sense of the word "[extensive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extensive?s=t)" that describes quantity of area. It is sometimes used to mean "quantity" in general, but it always has a connotative meaning that implies coverage of an area (whether spatial or abstract).

Comment: In what field is "extensive" used particularly for 2D surfaces?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I'm not sure that any discipline employs the two-dimensional meaning of the word as its primary meaning, but I have heard it used (and used it myself) in the two-dimensional sense in my studies of physics, philosophy, and mathematics. At least in philosophy and mathematics, I have more often heard it used to mean "having at least one spatial dimension."

Answer (score 2):

I think I would say ***spacious***.

How *long* is the string? How *voluminous* is the box? How ***spacious*** is the garden/living room/car park etc?

Comment: This only adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer to your question is, there simply **is not** an enlarging adjective form of "area" in English.

It's that simple.

You have to use any of the suggestions made here - expansive, large, big, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on *area*.

- I have found a piece of land with a huge/large area.
- I have found a sales job which covers an extensive area of the country.
- I have found an animal whose subspecies roam vast areas of the grasslands.
- We have found a way to cramp 1 trillion transistors into that minute area.
- We live in a house situated in the worst area of the town.
- We live in a phenomenal area of the city.
- Cousin Vinny, this town is the backwater of America, the most provincial area of the country.
- We live in a house where the backyard has inadequate area/space.
- Our farm has insufficient area to justify buying a combine harvester.
- In Montana, we had wide open areas. The sky was big but the houses had tiny areas.